# Transactional DDL options

Tags: sql, database

I have worked only with MySQL, and since finding out that DDLs perform implicit commit, I'm looking for a solution to obey it in MySQL.

In case MySQL cannot manage it even with some hacky method, a viable option is switching the SQL system. Are there any that allow transactional DDLs out-of-the-box or at least are simplier to set up than MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to make the DDL transactional in MySQL.

PostgreSQL has fully transactional DDL and personally I find it just as simple to setup and run as MySQL (actually I find MySQL more complicated to use because of all the limitations it's SQL dialect has).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this document](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Transactional_DDL_in_PostgreSQL%3a_A_Competitive_Analysis), PostgreSQL, DB2, Sybase, Informix and Firebird support transactional DDL, and in some cases SQL Server. Oracle auto-commits on every DDL statement, but has some additional "versioning" mechanisms.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? There may be better ways than transactional DDL.

Comment: I have a very dynamic application that is expanding upon itself - creates tables, alters, drops.